# Windows application using Python

Tags: python, ide, windows

I am used to Windows application development using C# .Net. Now that I got interested in Python I need to know the best way to create a Windows application that has stuffs like minimizing to System tray, nice ide like visual studio that has GUI way of developing apps. Any suggestions pls?

Comment: @Falmarri: What is wrong with asking this? And who are you to tell the OP that he should `stay out of real development`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this list on [GUI programming with Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming).

Scroll down to `GUI Design Tools and IDEs`. Take your pick, there are lots of choices.

Which one is the best? That depends on what you want to do. But for the purposes you mentioned, all should suffice.

Answer (score 4):

For C# programmer is [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I like WingIDE for python. There is an eclipse version too.

Comment: I am not asking for an ide. I need a windows application development tool for python.

Comment: @Vicky: How is that different than an IDE?

Comment: @Falmarri: How is it similar? He needs a GUI builder. How is that and an IDE, the same thing? Do all IDEs help you build GUIs?